# Using a curl command in a while loop

Tags: curl, while-loop, do-while

I am new to this so please bear with me.
I am trying to use a curl command in a while-do loop with little success.
I can use the curl command outside the loop to get a response but then when it hits the while loop it ignores the curl command and sticks with the first output to the file and not breaking the loop when it is done. 
The command i am running earlier outputs to web page the value of "2" meaning it has finished and the values "0,1 or 3" means it hasn't finished or errors etc.
As it can take time to complete the return of "2" can take some time hence the loop.
The values "0,1,2,3" are hard coded and cant be changed.
The code does work because if you cancel the programme from running, the file does get updated but it cant be seen in the loop process.I am stuck in the loop and cant break out of it because it wont revisit the webpage to look for "2"
Any ideas please
Here is a snippit of the code below

```
curl  --location http://$host_name/config-builder-test-app/jobStateResolver?jobId=$jobid > ./jobstate.txt

round=`grep -E "1|0|3" jobstate.txt`
while [ $round ]
do
curl  --location http://$host_name/config-builder-test-app/jobStateResolver?jobId=$jobid > ./jobstate.txt

echo "Waiting for confirmation of the completed build:";
sleep 5
done
echo "Successful build for $inputb ID $ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the "round" variable just get updated once before enter the while loop. You need to update that in the while loop, after running curl to get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Usually CURL can't be used in a loop construction. With each iteration another HTTPD session is used. However the data on the stack for the 'old' session will not have been released yet.
Unsetting the channel variable to release the stack, will not work, since the number of HTTPD sessions is the bad guy. We use 1 main HTTPD, spawning 4 sub-processes. So fur use after 5 iterations the loop will collaps.

So, there are 2 solutions to this problem.
EITHER either wait long enough for the 'old' HTTPD session to have gone, usually secs.
OR be fast enough, having the 'new' iterations, following the 'old', usually msecs

We concatenated all CURL output in a single memory array before processing it.